# Unity UI Input Field suddenly malfunctioned

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5.0.1f1, and my UI Input Fields are not working as they are supposed to.

I have an Input Field that is placed in a Panel and inside a Canvas. It has a Text component in which I can set text that the Input Field will display. When I change value of this Text component, the changes are not reflected on the Input Field, it seems to be reset to the value of Input Field (Script) \ Text of the Input Field.

If I enter Play mode, I can input text normally but when I build and run on my Android phone, I cannot input anything.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How can I solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It is generally a good idea to read the tag's description before using it.

Comment: Do you have Standalone Input Module and Touch Input Module components enabled on the EventSystem game object? They are created automatically when you create a new EventSystem, may be you disabled them somehow.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to report the problem in more detail than just "can't input anything". What happens when you touch the text field? What about other controls, like buttons, do they work?

Comment: About the EventSystem, both scripts are enabled.

more details:
- about "changes are not reflected on the Input Field" I mentioned above:
it's strange that when I create new Input Field, it did work normally (changes **are** reflected) but after I enter Play mode then stop Play mode, it did not work again. (changes **are not** reflected)

- about "can't input aything":
when I touch the text field, the keyboard appear and let me input things but after pressing "done" (to finish my inputs), there is nothing in the text field
the buttons worked, though

Comment: What if you create a new scene (in the same project), just with a lonely text field created from the UI menu, and nothing else? Does it work this way? If yes, what if you copy these exact text fields to this new scene, do they work?

Comment: newly created scene does not work :(
http://imgur.com/WiMhAcS

maybe I will try new project and another PC :(

Comment: Wait. Why do you expect entering text in the editor mode to work? There are two texts, the actual one and placeholder, and the actual one is supposed to be enabled only in runtime when the logic sees that the text that player put in is not empty.

Comment: isn't is supposed to work like that? :/
like the upper part of my image (newly created), when I change the text of Text component, the changes are reflected on the InputField

Comment: The point of the input field with a placeholder (and that's not just in Unity, but in UI in general) is that the logic switches between displaying the input text element and placeholder text element depending on whether the user has typed any text at all. If you're typing text as a user, you have to see it, of course.